# async method doesn't execute all the way through

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor-components

I have a method that adds some data to my database, it worked fine a while ago but now it has just stopped working.
I found out with debugging that my async method gets called but then just stops in the middle and the Answers are never getting added:

```
 private async Task CreateNewQuestion()
{
    if (newQuestion.QuestionType is null)
    {
        noType = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (Answers.Count == 0)
    {
        noAnswer = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (newQuestion.QuestionType is not null)
    {
        List<Question> questioncount = new List<Question>();
        questioncount = await questionRepo.GetQuestionByQuizId(QuizId);
        _order = questioncount.Count + 1;
        newQuestion.QuestionOrderId = _order;
        newQuestion.AnswerType = _answerType;
        newQuestion.QuestionUrl = _questionUrlConverted;
        await questionRepo.AddQuestionWithAnswers(newQuestion, Answers); <-- THIS IS WHERE THE METHOD GETS CALLED
        noType = false;
        questions = await questionRepo.GetQuestionByQuizId(QuizId);
        var quiz = quizRepo.GetQuizById(QuizId);

        Navigation.NavigateTo($"/Quiz/AddQuestionWithId/{QuizId}", true);
    }

}
```

and here is the method:

```
public async Task AddQuestionWithAnswers(Question newQuestion, List<Answer> answers)
    {
        if(newQuestion is not null && answers.Count > 0)
        {

            _context.Questions.Add(newQuestion);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); <-- THIS IS WHERE IT JUST STOPS TO EXECUTE

            var answerQuestionItem = await GetQuestionById(newQuestion.QuestionId);
            if(answerQuestionItem is not null)
            {
                foreach(var answer in answers)
                {
                    answer.Question = answerQuestionItem;
                    _context.Answers.Add(answer);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It also doesn't even go back to the method that called the method, just to my razor component and nothing happens.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you're code is throwing an error that you can't see by the method is async, add try-catch in your methods and check if an error is happening

Comment: Also, ensure you are not blocking on asynchronous code.